# Azure Functions fails in load testing in combination with Azure Cosmos DB or SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I got a large dataset of all the addresses in my country (3.8GB). I am creating an API which will query the database for one specific address and respond with basic JSON data (300bytes). The API is running in Python on Azure Functions.

So far everything works great. When I do a single request I get a response time of +/- 100-150ms. Great! but... If I try to load test the API with, let's say, 200 requests in 1 minute. The average response time is around 4-6 seconds.

This is what I tried so far

- Connect the API to a SQL database
- Connect the API to a Cosmos DB database
- Smaller tables (less columns)

Is there some limit on the number of connections per database? The SQL Database or Cosmos DB doesn't seem to be the issue (% of CPU/Mem are good).
I created a simple `/status` endpoint without the DB connection on the API which can handle 200 requests in 1 minute easily. Hopefully someone can push me in the right direction.

```python
    import azure.functions as func
    import os
    
    from azure.functions import AsgiMiddleware
    from fastapi import Query
    from typing import Optional
    from api_app import app
    
    import azure.cosmos.documents as documents
    import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client
    import azure.cosmos.exceptions as exceptions
    from azure.cosmos.partition_key import PartitionKey
    
    @app.get("/status")
    def get_status():
        return ({"status":  200})
    
    @app.get("/postcode_cosmosdb/{postcode}/{huisnummer}")
    async def postcode_cosmosdb(postcode: str, huisnummer: int):
        settings = {
            'host': os.environ.get('ACCOUNT_HOST', 'XXXXXX'),
            'master_key': os.environ.get('ACCOUNT_KEY', 'XXXXXX'),
            'database_id': os.environ.get('COSMOS_DATABASE', 'WoningAdressen'),
            'container_id': os.environ.get('COSMOS_CONTAINER', 'AdressenLight'),
        }
    
        HOST = settings['host']
        MASTER_KEY = settings['master_key']
        DATABASE_ID = settings['database_id']
        CONTAINER_ID = settings['container_id']
    
        client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(HOST, {'masterKey': MASTER_KEY}, user_agent="CosmosDBPythonQuickstart", user_agent_overwrite=True)
        db = client.get_database_client(DATABASE_ID)
        container = db.get_container_client(CONTAINER_ID)
    
        items = list(container.query_items(
            query="SELECT l.postcode, l.huisnummer, l.huisletter, l.nummeraanduiding_id as bagid, l.gemeente FROM AdressenLight as l WHERE l.postcode=@postcode AND l.huisnummer=@huisnummer",
            parameters=[
                { "name":"@postcode", "value": postcode },
                { "name":"@huisnummer", "value": huisnummer }
            ]
        ))
    
        return items
    
    def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
        return AsgiMiddleware(app).handle(req, context)
```

Comment: Can you share code? For your SQL and Cosmos database clients, are you maintaining a singleton client object? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#static-clients

Comment: Sure, thanks for your response. I edited my question with the python api code i got right now. So in my example i need to place the connection itself in a constructor or in the top of my script so it will not recreate a connection? But every request needs a connection itself so how would the script benefit from this?

Comment: Just tried to place the connection on the top of my script and only do the query in the function and i got around 110ms on average! Great! I just don't understand why it's working now. Is it because the connection 'lives' on the function/server for a period of time?

Comment: What is the partition key for this container? How much throughput (RU/s) do you have provisioned? How much RU/s does one of these queries cost?

Comment: What hosting option are you using for the Azure Function? (This impacts how the function will scale up under load.)

Comment: If you create a client on every function execution instead of reusing the same client, the client needs to keep opening connections every time, that is a latency penalty for every execution. I am not very familiar with Python but the effect of having a client declared as static or outside the scope of your Function execution code is that the instance is maintained and reused, and obviously the connections are reused. This applies to any type of client.

Answer (score 1):

It is official recommendation to reuse clients across function invocations. That keeps number of connections small and calls more efficient.

Please refer to docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections